# What does "operationally soluble" mean, re. Tax10 enzyme?

Tags: terminology, enzymes

I am trying to work out whether the enzyme Tax10 is soluble or insoluble. I need to know if some buffers won't work with Tax10. I am trying to confirm Tax10 activity, having confirmed protein expression and having purified it.
Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks :)

---

**Context:**

[Walker K, Long R, Croteau R. 2002. The final acylation step in taxol biosynthesis: cloning of the taxoid C13-side-chain N-benzoyltransferase from *Taxus*. Proc Natl Acad Sci USA 99(14):9166-9171.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC123112/pdf/pq1402009166.pdf)

> The TAX10 gene overexpressed from pSBET yielded a ≈50-kDa protein (determined by SDS/PAGE), consistent with the size of the encoded enzyme, and this operationally soluble recombinant enzyme from preparative bacterial cultures was partially purified by anion exchange (DE-52) and ceramic hydroxyapatite chromatography.

(p.9169, below Figure 3)

Comment: I think all they mean is that the protein was found in the soluble fraction rather than in inclusions.

Comment: Fantastic. I thought that's what they meant. Thanks :)